# problem with anaconda install unicode cp950

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

this is the problem, how can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: which package are you trying to install?

Comment: I just want to open anaconda promt but it shows this

Comment: Was it working before? Have you installed any packages recently?

Comment: My problem is because my c disk user name is in Chinese

Comment: This cause problem but I don’t know how to solve it

Comment: This error has occurred most likely due to that. If there are any characters in the `PATH` env. variables that cannot be encoded by Python, similar errors will appear.

Comment: Open a command prompt and type `echo %PYTHONIOENCODING%`. What number do you see?

Answer (score 1):

Use the windows "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" function.
This could save your time.